# Construction set which cloos to Vitali' s set

Tags: real-analysis

I want to constructe the Non-measureabl set such the following holds:

1) $V$ be a subset of $[0,1]$

2)$V$ is dense in $[0,1] $

3)outer measure $m^*(V)$ smaller than or equal $\epsilon$

This is my trying

I started to constructe an intervals as following

$I_1=[0,\epsilon]$     $I_2=[0,\epsilon/2] $.                            $I_3=[\epsilon/2,\epsilon]$,$I_4=[0,\epsilon]$,$I_5=[\epsilon/4,\epsilon/2]$,........

suppose $E_1,E_2,E_3,..........$ be sequence of distinct  equivalence class of the relation the same when define Vitali set. And then select exactly one of $E_i$ of $I_i$

Therefore, we will get the desired set

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Sorry , this is just typing mistake

Comment: Consider constructing a Vitali set in a very small interval and then forming the union with all rational numbers in $[0,1].$ A more interesting example would be to replace "dense in $[0,1]$" with "has non-measurable intersection with every nonempty open subinterval of $[0,1]"$ (properties 1 and 3 are still required to hold).